# Instead of 'Break'

Tags: python, break

I tried to use boolean instead of 'break' , but I could not manage to do that. Is there a way to edit this code without 'break' ?

Primes:

```
lower = int(input("Enter the lower bound: "))
upper = int(input("Enter the upper bound: "))

for num in range(lower,upper+1):
    if num>1 :
        for i in range(2,num):
            if(num%i) == 0:
                break
        else:
             print(num, end =", ")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to get rid of the `break` and preserve the same behavior of exiting the inner loop as soon as `num % i == 0`. This is one way to do it, using a boolean flag and replacing the `for` with a `while` so we can add one extra condition for the iteration:

```
for num in range(max(2, lower), upper + 1):
    i = 2
    prime = True
    while i < num and prime:
        if num % i == 0:
            prime = False
        i += 1
    if prime:
        print(num, end=", ")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could replace `break` with `pass`. I think that will do what you want.

Comment: This is not at all what OP is asking...

Comment: And `pass` does nothing, it certainly won't make you `break` out of the current loop.